# Why does git rebase with no arguments work the way that it does?

Tags: git, rebase

Every so often I'll perform a `git rebase` with no arguments and discover that instead of rebasing against my configured upstream, Git has used the `--fork-point` option and rebased against...something else, causing my commits to disappear.

This is in line with what the documentation for [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) says:

> If <upstream> is not specified, the upstream configured in branch.<name>.remote and branch.<name>.merge options will be used (see git-config[1] for details) and the `--fork-point` option is assumed.

My question is: *Why* does it work this way?  Personally, I feel that if I run `git rebase` with no options, I want to rebase against the configured upstream branch.  If I wanted to rebase against something else, I'd say so.

Apparently the developers of Git think otherwise, so I'm wondering whether someone can explain the thinking in a way that'll help me remember this distinction.

Comment: For what it's worth (perhaps not much), I, too, am uncomfortable with the automatic `--fork-point` mode here. I suspect that on a statistical basis, it's more helpful for more users than it is harmful. What makes me uncomfortable is that the degree of harm, when it does occur, is high. (Note, though, that your elided commits are still available to you-as-a-power-user via your reflogs and your `ORIG_HEAD`, though you must notice soon enough that they have gone missing.)

Comment: @torek, thanks for the edit.  Yeah, the annoying thing is that `git rebase` _often_ works as I would expect, but not _always_.  If I've split off a branch as described by Mark below, it doesn't work as I'd expect.  It's simple enough to go to the reflog, hard-reset my branch back, and re-run the rebase with a branch argument.  The link I posted below is interesting.  _Pace_ Junio Hamano, who knows more about Git than I ever will, I don't think the commit he mentions caused this problem, because I remember noticing it a bit less than a year earlier (when I had just started a new job).

Comment: @RyanLundy and @torek I totally agree. Personally, I only ever accidentally hit 'Enter' after typing `git rebase` than use it bare. Until a remote is added, `git rebase` by itself doesn't work, and I have to enter the upstream (branch) anyway, so I'm used to being explicit about it. It's easy to forget after a `git remote add ...` that bare `git rebase` rebases against the upstream remote, the additional automatic `--fork-point` notwithstanding. I would rather it force me to enter the upstream rather than sift through `reflog` to undo an accidental change (it's only a few chars to type).

Answer (score 1):

I made a test with 2 local repos.

```
#simulate a remote repo
git init server
cd server
> a
git add .
git commit -m 'a'
git branch new
> b
git add .
git commit -m 'b'
git checkout new
> c
git add .
git commit -m 'c'
git checkout master
cd -
```

And the graph by `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` is:

```
* 912e28a (HEAD -> master) b
| * 8c71449 (new) c
|/
* bd95493 a
```

The other repo that simulates a local one:

```
git clone server -- client
cd client
git reset HEAD^ --hard
> d
git add .
git commit -m 'd'
```

And the graph:

```
* 7173a5f (HEAD -> master) d
| * 912e28a (origin/master, origin/HEAD) b
|/
| * 8c71449 (origin/new) c
|/
* bd95493 a
```

`origin/master` is the upstream branch of `master`. Now run `git rebase` and the graph becomes:

```
* 3bc57c5 (HEAD -> master) d
* 912e28a (origin/master, origin/HEAD) b
| * 8c71449 (origin/new) c
|/
* bd95493 a
```

The graph is the same result of `git rebase origin/master` or `git rebase origin/master master`.

Then make another try with the upstream branch changed:

```
#go back to the graph before the rebase
git reset 7173a5f --hard
#change the upstream
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/new
git status
#try rebase again, without arguments
git rebase
```

The graph turns to:

```
* b3bfd13 (HEAD -> master) d
* 8c71449 (origin/new) c
| * 912e28a (origin/master, origin/HEAD) b
|/
* bd95493 a
```

as if `git rebase origin/new` or `git rebase origin/new master` has been run.

So I think it does behave as you've been expecting, rebasing the current branch against its upstream. I wonder which commits were gone in your case.

Merge commits disappear without `-p` or `--preserve-merges`. If the upstream has equivalent commits already, commits on the current branch are gone too.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasing of the question ("rebased against... something else") suggests that you either aren't sure of, or don't buy into, what `fork-point` is supposed to do.  If we start from a clear picture of what it does (and if we assume it works properly and doesn't have destructive side-effects), then the motivation for using it as the default might seem more clear.

(I'll be honest, I'd never bothered to figure out what `fork-point` does prior to looking at this question.  The best explanation seems to be in the `git merge-base` documentation - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base.)

Before getting into the weeds, two "big picture" observations:

1) I don't think the git developers would agree that using `fork-point` means you're "rebasing against something else"; I think they'd probably say that you're still rebasing against the upstream, but are being more selective about which commits to rewrite on the new base.

2) While `fork-point` may not always be useful, it's not clear to me in what scenario it would cause your commits to disappear[1].  It would be interesting to see any minimal test cases that show problems (since above I mentioned "assume no destructive side-effecdts" as a condition of thinking this is a reasonable default).

So getting into it...

*What is fork-point trying to do?*

The short answer is, if a commit was previously part of the upstream and was removed from the upstream via history edit, then `--fork-point` tells rebase to leave that commit behind on the grounds that (1) it's not really part of the branch, (2) it's been rejected from the upstream already, and (3) we probably aren't trying to undo someone's history rewrite.

It does this by inferring information from the reflogs.  Because the reflogs are local and temporary, this is a bit of a kludge; your attempt to rebase could get a different result from someone else's attempt to perform the same rebase in a seemingly-identical clone of the repo.

And if your reflogs seem to suggest that what is in fact your commit was once part of the upstream, that could cause a problem.

*So why use it as a default?*

I guess the bottom line is, the developers assume that if a commit was previously in the upstream and was removed from the upstream, that removal was definitive.  Whether that is "usually true" may depend on the developer.

The odd thing is, the example used in the `merge-base` docs (cited above) seems like an odd one.  It shows the upstream as `origin/master`, which implies that at some point the remote's `master` was rewritten - which is an upstream rebase situation, which is generally discouraged.

For unrelated reasons, I'm in the habit of always specifying my upstream when I rebase.  This means, depending on how you look at it, that I miss out on the benefit of and/or am never subjected to the risk of a default `fork-point` option.

---

[1] I did come up with one potential case, but I'm not sure if it's the case you're running into.  In the event you're on master, and you start developing a feature, and only after committing you realize that you forgot to create the feature branch; so you create the branch "in place" and then rewind `master` to un-mingle your changes; then rebasing the feature to master with fork-point could do the wrong thing.

One solution that might help with this case would be, after rewinding master, you could do a force rebase to regenerate your branch from fresh commits that are not in the master reflog.

Comment: I think [1] is precisely the case I'm running into.  In such a situation, the behavior of `git rebase` makes no sense to me.  Why would the developers of Git assume that if I remove a commit from a branch, that I _never ever_ want that commit to be allowed to be in that branch again?  Why would the default behavior of `git rebase` in such a case be `throw those commits away`?

Comment: The thing about the solution you mention is that it's one of those "you just have to remember..." things.  If I can remember to force a rebase when I create a new branch and remove its commits from the original branch, then I can also (more simply) remember never to use `git rebase` without specifying the upstream, which is probably less typing anyway.  By the way, when researching this, I ran across this exchange, which seems relevant: [Usability issue with rebase fork-point option](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqbmivyih1.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/t/)

Comment: The answer to the questions underlying both of your comments is: you're supposed to create the branch before you start committing to it. Not trying to be a jerk about it, but that is what git expects you to do. If you make the first commit on master and then need to remove it, in the git developers' thinking that was a mistake; and so yes, you have to remember how to clean up after a mistake. They wrote git to assume that what it sees is not a mistake, but instead was deliberate; i.e. it assumes commit X were deliberately made as part of master, and then deliberately removed from master.

Comment: btw: In the question, you originally asked for explanation of the logic behind the default so you could understand and remember; so that's what I've given.  But since your response from there is to *argue* with that thinking, it does suggest a different motivation.  I'm not saying the thinking is good or bad, but the default is what it is, so it might be more productive to take that at face value than to keep reinforcing why you think it "should" be different.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think I'm arguing.

Comment: @RyanLundy - I think you're arguing because, presented with the rationale for making this the default, you respond by explaining why you think it shouldn't be. That is, by definition, arguing with the rationale; and my point is, while I'm presenting the reason, I'm not going to argue to defend it. I only observe that it is, and you can take from that what you want. So if you don't like my proposed solution, don't use it. I would (if I weren't in habit of specifying the upstream anyway) because it solves the problem *right then* instead of waiting to remember to specify the upstream later...

Comment: @RyanLundy - ... but that's me, and you can develop in what way you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the signature of `git rebase` is

`git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream> <branch>`

where the commits between `<branch>` and the `merge base` of `<branch>` and `<upstream>` (i.e. the value returned from the plumbing command `git merge-base`) are replayed onto `<newbase>`. (`merge base` is so-called because it returns the would-be `<base>` commit of a 3-way merge between `<branch>` and `<upstream>`; "3" in "3-way" because such merges involve the tip commits `<branch>` and `<upstream>` and base `<base>`). In this context, we can think of `merge base` as "fork point".

Typically, the user checks out the branch they want to rebase and specifies the upstream in the command with

`git rebase <upstream>`

which gets interpreted as

`git rebase --onto <upstream> <upstream> HEAD`.

If the branch to rebase has a tracking branch, `rebase` can be called by itself without options or arguments and it will be replayed onto the tracking branch (e.g. `origin/branch`) as

`git rebase --onto <origin/branch> <origin/branch> HEAD`

In this case though, `rebase` replays the commits between HEAD and `git merge-base --fork-point` of HEAD and `origin/branch`, which is slightly different than the `git merge-base` of HEAD and `origin/branch`. AFAIK, this helps when the branch and remote used to point to the same base, but the remote later got replayed onto a different base.

Whenever `upstream` is specified, `--fork-point` is not used by default, so my best guess is that the Git developers wanted `--fork-point` to be default when a remote upstream is specified and they didn't have a way to differentiate between a local upstream and a remote upstream. A solution for them would then be to introduce `git rebase` by itself, switching the default option from `--no-fork-point` to `--fork-point` in that case, and only make it work when a tracking branch is set for the branch.

Still, I think letting the command run successfully without options is dangerous (as it may be run by accident before options and arguments are entered). If you'd like to run `git rebase` by itself and have it run as it does when you specify an upstream, you have to explicitly supply `--no-fork-point` (i.e. `git rebase --no-fork-point`). Again, this only works when the branch has a tracking branch.